# Spring Boot 2.1.0 with Jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

Today i started a simple application spring boot application. Because i am starting from the scratch, i am using the latest version of SpringBoot: 2.1.0.RELEASE

I would like to use Jersey to use JAX-RS. I have this working for 1.3.6 Spring Boot version, but I am getting the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'requestContextFilter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I can't understand where the problem could be because my application at this point is minimalist.

Apparently the bean 'requestContextFilter' is being configured twice but i have no idea where it is configured.

Here is my configuration:

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>pt.msoftware.userauthservice.App</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>${user.name}</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**SpringBoot application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

** Jersey Config**

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import pt.msoftware.userauthservice.rest.UserEndpoint;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

/**
 * Created by marco on 31/10/2018.
 */
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(UserEndpoint.class);
    }

}
```

** Endpoint**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

/**
 * Created by marco on 31/10/2018.
 */
@Component
@Path("/user")
public class UserEndpoint {
    @GET
    public String message() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Can someone spot what I am missing or what might be wrong with my code/config?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug in Spring Boot. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15048) to track the problem.

If you intend to only use Jersey and JAX-RS, you do not need to use `spring-boot-starter-web`. It's, essentially, a Spring MVC-based equivalent of `spring-boot-starter-jersey`. You can, therefore, avoid the problem you're seeing by removing the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency from your application.

If you do want to use both Spring MVC and JAX-RS, you can enable bean definition overriding by adding `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to your `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Your suggestion worked perfectly. My intention is just to create a service, so removing spring-boot-starter-web works perfectly.

Can I ask your opinion. Is there a strong reason to use JAX-RS over Spring REST? It is just a different flavour? Best regards